# Ruby on Rails: more verbose tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automated-tests

This test keeps failing and I don't know why:

```
  test "correctly formatted profile_name2" do
    user = User.new(first_name: 'Jim', last_name: 'Johnson', email: 'jim@teamtreehouse.com', password: 'awfawwf', profile_name: "jimmy")
    puts user.errors.inspect
    assert user.valid?
  end
```

I tried to find out by that `puts user.errors.inspect` statement, but I get back an array (I think) that simply lists database input rather than precisely what's failing.

For clarification:

```
<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00000103c8ad30 @base=#<User id: nil, first_name: "Jim", last_name: "Johnson", profile_name: "jimmy", email: "jim@teamtreehouse.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$LTOb5O.gG0DEITsb/HDOb.fPLP83LaXzKlEerwCDE1og...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, authentication_token: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={}>
```

In future tests, what statements are used in tests to print to screen explicitly what's going wrong?

Comment: user.errors.full_messages will give you a prettier format, but since there are no messages in the output, idk why user isn't valid

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of outputting more verbose information within your tests, it might also help to set the TESTOPTS argument to get verbose output when you run your tests.

For example you would set it like this:

```
rake test TESTOPTS="-v"
```

Comment: Almost six years later your answer helped me get verbose output for Rails system tests!

Answer (score 0):

As someone who is new to Ruby on Rails, I can confirm that the accepted answer is still valid for Rails 7. However, I would like to offer an alternative way of achieving the same result.

Instead of using the command `rake test TESTOPTS="-v"`, you can use the shorthand option `-v` provided by the command `rails test` like this:

```
rails test -v
```

This command will produce the same verbose output as the previous command.

I hope this helps.